# Suitable data structure for finding a person's phone number, given their name?

Tags: data-structures

Suppose you want to write a program that implements a simple phone book. Given a particular name, you want to be able to retrieve that person's phone number as quickly as possible. What data structure would you use to store the phone book, and why?

Comment: Even if your question is urgent, next time, please reflect a little longer on the question title. I've attempted to rephrase it for you so that it's a little more specific than just "Help! Data structure!".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the text below answers your question.

> In computer science, a hash table or hash map is a data structure that
>   uses a hash function to map identifying values, known as keys **(e.g., a
>   person's name)**, to their associated values **(e.g., their telephone
>   number)**. Thus, a hash table implements an associative array. The hash
>   function is used to transform the key into the index (the hash) of an
>   array element (the slot or bucket) where the corresponding value is to
>   be sought.

the text is from wiki:hashtable.

there are some further discussions, like collision, hash functions... check the wiki page for details.

Comment: Thank you. the right structure was all i needed. the details i am somewhat familiar with. wanted to get a second opinion. thanks again.

Comment: Well. I understand the solution. What if we have to store phone numbers of two different persons with same name?

Comment: @Sandeep According to the specification, that wouldn't be possible. If you have a phonebook containing two "John Doe", one with phone number 112233 and one with phone number 445566, and I asked you to give me the phone number of John Doe, what would you do?

Well the only thing you could do would be to give me both numbers. (Corresponding to a hashmap which maps each name to a list of phone numbers).

Ideally, however, you'd want something unique as the key. Maybe, if the information is available, the social security number could be used as the key in the hash map instead.

Answer (score 5):

I respect & love hashtables :) but even a balanced binary tree would be fine for your phone book application giving you in worst case a logarithmic complexity and avoiding you for having good hash functions, collisions etc. which is more suitable for huge amounts of data.

When I talk about huge data what I mean is something related to storage. Every time you fill all of the buckets in a hash-table you will need to allocate new storage and re-hash everything. This can be avoided if you know the size of the data ahead of time. Balanced trees wont let you go into these problems. Domain needs to be considered too while designing data structures, for an example for small devices storage matters a lot.

Comment: Wow you guys are good :) My first question here. I really liked your explanation Yavar.

Comment: @user1257444: welcome to world of stack overflow. It is a classic example of collective intellligence at work. Be a part of it.Please change your default name "user1257444" to something meaningful, for an example "spiderman" :)

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering why 'Tries' didn't come up in one of the answers,
`Tries` is suitable for Phone book kind of data.

Also, saving space compared to `HashTable` at the same cost(almost) of Retrieval efficiency, (assuming constant size alphabet & constant length Names)

Tries also facilitate the `'Prefix Matches'` sometimes required while searching.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is both dynamic and fast.

Answer (score 0):

You want a dictionary, where you use the name as the key, and the number as the data stored. Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_%28data_structure%29

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a singly linked list? Each node will have the name, number and link information.

One drawback is that your  search might take some time since you'll have to traverse the entire list from link to link. You might order the list at the time of node insertion itself!

PS: To make the search a tad bit faster, maintain a link to the middle of the list. Search can continue to the left or right of the list based on the value of the "name" field at this node. Note that this requires a doubly linked list.

Comment: Your postscript requires a doubly-linked list; however you are proposing a singly-linked list (which btw. I would not recommend for this problem because of the linear search time issue that you mention).

Comment: @stakx: Thanks for pointing out the mistake in my ps. Forgot to mention about the doubly linked list there.